# Fire multiple select from one table and insert the result into Target table using node-red dashdb-in and dashdb-out modules

Tags: node.js, for-loop, node-red

I am trying to achieve to read from a DB2 table and insert to a different DB2 table using node-red.  For this i am using dashdb modules(https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-nodes-cf-sqldb-dashdb). I have made sure that columns are matching in both source and target and tested to insert multiple records in target table using  select query as select * from source_table and then insert query for the insert table.
Now i have another thing in which i need to fire multiple select queries on source table and insert the result records in target table asynchronously.
All the multiple select queries would be identical except where id = ? . So i tried to put the query in msg.payload inside a for loop like this

```
var queryID = 2; // max number of id to be querying against
            for (i=1; i<=queryID; i++) { 
                console.log("COUNT", i)
                msg.payload = `select * from source_table where id= ${i}` // only i changes
                node.send(msg); // i pass it to next node which is dashBD out node responsible for selecting record from source table
            }
```

But doing this only executes the last  loop value which is 2 and do not node.send the value where i = 1 to the next node.

Can anyone shed some light here: It inserts the result with id=2 two times in the target table. Instead i want to execute insert according to the for loop i variable. This is the second node module function in the graph

```
module.exports = function(RED) {
function fireMultipleQuery(nodeConfig) {
    RED.nodes.createNode(this,nodeConfig);
    var node = this;
    node.on('input', function(msg) {
        var queryID = 2; // max number of id to be querying against
        for (i=1; i<=queryID; i++) { 
            console.log("COUNT", i)
            msg.payload = `select * from source_table where id= ${i}` // only i changes
            node.send(msg); // i pass it to next node which is dashBD out node responsible for selecting record from source table
        });

     }
    RED.nodes.registerType("fire-query-node", fireMultipleQuery);
}
```

This is my flow
[image]

Comment: What version of Node-RED are you using?

Comment: Node-RED version: v1.1.3
Node.js  version: v8.12.0

Comment: What is the second node in the chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NodeJS is a pass by reference language.

So because the loop is updating the same `msg` object it is changing the already sent version as well.

You will probably want to clone the `msg` or create a new object for each send.

You can clone messages with `RED.util.cloneMessage()`

Comment: Thanks! It works when i use msg = RED.util.cloneMessage(msg); Trying to understand